# InputStream receives incomplete data

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream

I am using a Socket connection to connect to a database. When I pull data from the database via InputStream, sometimes it returns full data but most of the time it returns incomplete data (5%/95%). There's an EOF that the database sends but it only gets that far about 5% of the time.

```
    @Override
    protected Socket doInBackground(Void... params) {


        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = new Socket(SocketHelper.IP_ADDRESS, SocketHelper.PORT);

            //output message
            OutputStream output = client.getOutputStream();
            output.write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));


            //parse response 
    //blocks here more of the time
            SocketHelper.parseData(client.getInputStream());


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return client;
    }
```

In my parse method, I look for the EOF and would normally close the InputStream and close the Socket there. I can't find any consistencies for the times it does reach the EOF. Right now the length of the data is static, I haven't adjusted it while I"m trying to figure this out. But the length of the data will be dynamic.

Comment: What does `SocketHelper.parseData` do?

Comment: Indeed. Without that knowledge your question isn't answerable.

Comment: SockerHelper.parseData creates a BufferedReader with the InputStream returned from client.getInputStream(); while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) ....

Answer (score -1):

To read data from a `Socket`, in your `parseData` method you need to loop, calling [`read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) until all the bytes you expect have arrived.

The `read` method returns the number of bytes actually read; keep looping until you've got everything. Remember to adjust the offset argument, so that you build up the full message.